# MongoDB remove rows where _id != (id of list)

Tags: mongodb

I have collection in MongoDB. And I have list of id's:

```
63914429b17ce610372ea481
63914486b17ce610372ea54f
641d78cb036719f3470fc75d
```

How can I create a function to remove all rows from table where _id != one of from this id's?

So I need the same function, but for removing only 10 first rows.

How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to first retrieve 10 items to delete that are not in the ID list using [`$nin`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/):

```
const listOfIds = [ ... ]
const toBeDeleted = db.collection('collection-name')
  .find({ $nin: listOfIds })
  .limit(10)
  .toArray()
  .map((doc) => doc._id);
```

Then, delete the retrieved ids using [`$in`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/):

```
db.collection('collection-name').remove({ _id: { $in: listOfIds } });
```